# Installing Thrift on CentOS: can't find Boost 1.40 or higher

Tags: boost, centos, thrift

I can't shake this error when trying to install Thrift:

```
    ./configure
    ...
    checking for boostlib >= 1.40.0... configure: WARNING: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.40 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
```

I'm using CentOS. As per the Thrift [docs on CentOS](http://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/centos/), I've done

```
sudo yum install automake libtool flex bison pkgconfig gcc-c++ boost-devel libevent-devel zlib-devel python-devel ruby-devel
```

I've tried using `--with-boost` to no avail.

I've also done:

```
[]# yum install boost141
Setting up Install Process
Package boost141-1.41.0-2.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[]# yum install boost141-devel
Setting up Install Process
Package boost141-devel-1.41.0-2.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package boost141-devel-1.41.0-2.el5.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

So now I have:

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-18-3D-20 include]# find / -name boost
/usr/local/bin/boost
/usr/include/boost141/boost
/usr/include/boost
```

Through various googling, I've found people with this error who say, 'Oh it was gcc-c++, I didn't have that installed,' but as far as I can tell, I have gcc-c++ installed:

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-18-3D-20 boost]# yum install gcc-c++
rightscale-epel                                                                                                                                                                                                   |  951 B     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Package gcc-c++-4.1.2-46.el5_4.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I recently hit the same thing working with a Cent 5.10 machine and building Thrift

Fixup the include files for boost141 and the build will work.

```bsh
ln -s /usr/include/boost141/boost /usr/include/boost
```