# How can I let Graph-tool find boost libraries and install it?

Tags: boost, graph-tool

I am trying to install Graph-tool, but the following error is returned.

```
./cofigure
...
...
graph-tool will be installed at: /home/my_name/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
===========================
Using python version: 2.7.12
===========================
checking for boostlib >= 1.54.0... configure: We could not detect the boost libraries (version 1.54 or higher). If you have a staged boost library (still not installed) please specify $BOOST_ROOT in your environment and do not give a PATH to --with-boost option.  If you are sure you have boost installed, then check your version number looking in <boost/version.hpp>. See http://randspringer.de/boost for more documentation.
checking whether the Boost::Python library is available... yes
checking whether boost_python is the correct library... yes
checking whether the Boost::IOStreams library is available... yes
configure: error: Could not link against boost_python !
```

It seems this error is same as 
[Installing Thrift on CentOS: can't find Boost 1.40 or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616762/installing-thrift-on-centos-cant-find-boost-1-40-or-higher)
. So I guess I should make an appropriate symbolic link to let the configure file find the path to the boost libraries. But I'm not sure where I should make the link because the result of "find" command is different from the asker of the above-mentioned question.

```
[root@localhost my_name]# su
[root@localhost my_name]# find / -name boost
/home/my_name/python/graph-tool-2.19/src/boost-workaround/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/doc/test/gold/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/tools/boostbook/test/doxygen/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/boost/chrono/typeof/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/boost/hana/ext/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/sort/doc/html/header/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/sort/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/chrono/stopwatches/include/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/hana/example/ext/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/hana/test/ext/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/vmd/doc/html/header/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/convert/doc/html/header/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/convert/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/functional/overloaded_function/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/math/include_private/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/compute/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/pool/doc/html/header/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/tti/doc/html/header/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/tti/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/icl/doc/html/header/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/header/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/core/doc/html/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/header/boost
/home/my_name/boost_1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/6_Advanced/interval/boost
/usr/include/boost
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem ? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I managed to solve this problem by my self.

It seems the error occurred because the Boost was actually not installed properly.

This time, I did:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ tar --bzip2 -xf boost_1_63_0.tar.bz2
$ cd boost_1_63_0.tar.bz2
$ sh ./bootstrap.sh
$ sudo ./b2 install
```

Then, I found the following directories.

```
$ sudo find / -name boost

/home/tokudakeita/python/graph-tool-2.19/src/boost-workaround/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/doc/test/gold/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/tools/boostbook/test/doxygen/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/boost/chrono/typeof/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/boost/hana/ext/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/sort/doc/html/header/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/sort/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/chrono/stopwatches/include/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/hana/example/ext/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/hana/test/ext/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/vmd/doc/html/header/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/convert/doc/html/header/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/convert/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/functional/overloaded_function/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/math/include_private/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/compute/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/pool/doc/html/header/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/tti/doc/html/header/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/tti/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/icl/doc/html/header/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/header/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/numeric/odeint/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/core/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/header/boost
/usr/local/boost_1_63_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/6_Advanced/interval/boost
/usr/local/include/boost
/usr/local/include/boost/chrono/typeof/boost
/usr/local/include/boost/hana/ext/boost
```

What I found was that just

```
$ ./b2
```

does not create the following directories:

```
/usr/local/include/boost
/usr/local/include/boost/chrono/typeof/boost
/usr/local/include/boost/hana/ext/boost
```

But the following command made the above directories:

```
$ sudo ./b2 install
```

Then, the configure file of the Graph-tool successfully found boost.